# An simple algebra problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Could someone check if my algebra is right?

If $x_n = \dfrac{1}{a^{a^n}}$ where $a > 1$ and $a$ is natural number, what is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|b_{n+1}|}{|b_n|^R}$$? Where $b_n = x_{2n}$ and $R$ is any real number.

I believe if I didn't screw up my algebra,

$$\lim a^{a^{a^n}(R - a^a)} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &R =a^a \\ 
 \infty& R > a^a \\ 
 0&  R < a^a
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is incorrect. Instead, you should end up with $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{a^{2n}(R-a^2)}.$$

Of course, it looks like you know how to get the rest if you can get up to the limit above.